# Rendering with AMD Radeon R5 M330 gives an error that I can't understand!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

So lately I started making an animation that has a lot of detailed objects, which made it render very slowly on my Core i5-6200 (clocked @ 2.30 GHz).
I'm using the Cycles rendering engine (Internal rendering engine doesn't support GPU rendering so it's obvious that I'm using Cycles).
To make it render faster I tried rendering using my AMD Radeon R5 M330, but It always said "errors in console" in the bar in the top that shows the time since the beginning of the render, the frame number and the samples rendered (or tiles when rendering an animation). Then when I open the console from Window>Toggle Console this I find this error:
[image]
I know that Blender's support for OpenCL is very limited, but maybe there is a solution for this error...

Also you can tell me some other ways to speed up the rendering proccess without reducing samples that will result in quality loss (in my animations the number of samples was set to 50 when I tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 2.78 which has since been fixed in master ([bug T49846](https://developer.blender.org/T49846), fixed in [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rC5bb349a14d97ced0132656cfce7ce49ef979d928)).

Luckily you don't have to wait, you can fix this bug yourself. Edit the following file:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\kernel_projection.h
```

On line 238:

```
    float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
```

should read:

```
    float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf((*D).z));
```